# Moving the file pointer in read/write linux Character Devices

Tags: c, linux, io, char, driver

I'm writing a character device driver, and I'm unable to find any useful information about how to change the file pointer on user reading/writing in my situation.

My driver expects user input of 8 bytes, and returns an 8-byte value on read. By design, writes MUST be in 8 byte chunks, one at a time.

The driver only contains the last 2 pieces of data written, so I feel like I should not be advancing the loff_t pointer by 8 every time. Actually, I feel like I should be resetting to zero, such that the user only writes to positions 0 and 8 with each successive write (going back and forth).

On read, the driver returns the sum/difference/etc of these two values (controlled by ioctl)

What are the standards for this type of reading and writing into a character device driver?

I am unable to find any documentation that explicitly speaks of how I should manage this.

Comment: Many character devices are not seekable, so you cannot move the file pointer using them (pipes, terminals, …).  Yours sounds as if is one such device.

Comment: That makes sense. Does that mean standard read and write would be unsupported? And only pread and pwrite work?

Comment: No — character devices normally support both read and write.  Think pipes, terminals. In the old days, disk drives had block and character devices, and both supported read and write (and, indeed, seek).  It is up to the driver to provide a seek option if it makes sense; if. it doesn't make sense, then don't provide it — generate an error instead (ESPIPE — Illegal seek).